# Regex symbol for " ' "

Tags: java, android, regex

I know of symbols like Quotations `"&quote;"` require a special intake on regexing on Java. I want to know about the symbol " ' ".

Also if possible could someone link me to where I can find the symbol names.

The reason I am doing this is because in my string are a bunch of weird symbols and I am using this regex to remove all symbols except for the few selected.

```
String string = ""Hello&*(#$%Everyone!,\n is everyone a good time."";//Sample string requested by someone

string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,.\n-&quote;?]+", " ");
```

There you go I added a runnable example of testing

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,.\n[-][']&quote;?]+", " ");& 
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,.\n-'&quote;?]+", " ");
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: No they don't require a special intake. Perhaps you're thinking of how to escape characters in Java strings? That would be through using a backslash (\\).

Comment: Symbol is just `"'"`. What is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to make sure that the symbol doesn't get taken out of my regex of string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,.\n-&quote;?]+", " ");

Comment: Double quotes do not need special handling on regexp side. They do need special handling on Java side (namely, escaping). This does not apply to single quotes. Characters that do require special handling on regexp side are meta-characters, such as `*`, `+`, `(`, etc. The simplest way to deal with them is enclosing in `[]`, e.g. `[.]` matches  a period, while `.` matches any character.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did try your method using string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,.\n[-][']&quote;?]+", " "); The data still persist in removing my ' and -.

Comment: Can you provide a sample value of string variable?

Comment: I am using an html string hmm...Let me make a string which looks similar to it.

Comment: @Mac I also tried that. First thing I tried it didn't work to my surprise.

Comment: Could you give us a complete, runnable example that demonstrates what you are trying to do (but presumably doesn't quite get there)? It seems clear that there's a lot of confusion about what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @aix done. I added the stuff found on the question tab.

Comment: `[&quote;]` means "matches an ampersand, or a 'q', or a 'u', or an 'o', or a 't' or an 'e' or a semicolon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I got to thank all of you who placed a lot of efforts trying to help me solve my issue. Apparently HTML have this symbols ’ , ‘ which are not register as '.

and here is the fix

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w!’‘,.\n'&quote;&apose;?]+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the symbol in between the brackets [']

No escaping is required

Comment: If you DON'T want to remove the ' , use `[^']`  ... Also, put the brackets around ALL the characters at once.  Such as `[^'A-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

If you try code like this:

```
String string = "Hello&*(#$%Everyone!,\n is everyone's a good time.?"; 
System.out.printf("[%s]%n", string.replaceAll("[^\\w!,'.\n?-]+", " "));
```

the OUTPUT is:

```
[Hello Everyone!,
 is everyone's a good time.?]
```

You can see quote `'` is preserved in the output string.

Comment: Can you try the regex from my answer with your actual html string?

Comment: Thanks a lot though I really appreciate you going testing for me. Kinda tested my butt off with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string = string.replaceAll("[w!,.\n-'?]+", " ");`. You use `^` sign witch means: "not one of the following", so don't be surprised puting `'` there cannot find it. There is nothing like `&quote` in java regex.

Comment: What!?! Give me two strings: input one and output you would like to have.

Comment: Would you like me to email you on how it looks like? Can't just place everything on the screen. Still doesn't accept it. However! on normal Java it accepts it not android 2.2.